# Comparing MySQL table record with user entered value in PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql-python, control-flow

Here I'm basically trying to fetch a string value from the SQL Table and I want to compare that value with the string I entered. I tried this simple way but unfortunately, it isn't working. I need help.[image: CurrentOutput]

```
def cantkt():
    #tkt()
    #canstate=("DELETE FROM Chart WHERE PNR=%s"%canpnr)
    canpnr=input("Enter PNR No. to Cancel Ticket: ")
    mycsr.execute("SELECT PNR FROM Chart WHERE PNR=%s"%canpnr)
    res=mycsr.fetchone()
    print(res)
    if res==canpnr:
         print("PNR MATCHED")
    else:
         print("PNR No. DOES NOT MATCH")
```

Comment: I think if you had two debug print statements you would have caught this on your own.  ```print(res)``` and then ```print(canpnr)```  It would have made it really plain for you why they didn't match :)

Comment: No that's not the issue, if you have a look at the output, you'll see both of them have the same values.

Comment: But they don't have the same values.  One would print ```('1019654419',)``` and the other would print ```1019654419```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see in the print, the result of the fetching is a tuple, not a string.

You can do simply this:

```
res = mycsr.fetchone()
if res: res = res[0]
```

Explanation:

res is ('1019654419', ) so you must seek the value you want to get, in this case the first one.

In "if res: res = res[0]" we check if res has a value because in case the ticket does not exist the fetching value would be an empty tuple, so trying to get the first result will raise an IndexError.